# Android Error on Java VM. Running Java SE 7

Tags: java, android, macos

Alright, so I have an internal error, meaning the code runs on all computers, but I have an internal error that I cannot understand and don't know how to fix.

```
#
#  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:129), pid=11983, tid=5891
#  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
#
# JRE version: 7.0_17-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/ColinRioux/Desktop/Hangman/hs_err_pid11983.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I am running JRE 7 for MacOSX (Default). Operating System: Latest Release of Mavericks (fully updated).

Comment: It might be helpful to show us that error log.

Comment: This is the error Log. This is from console. The project runs fine on other computers, this is my error.

Comment: @Todd means the part that says: "An error report file with more information is saved as: /Users/ColinRioux/Desktop/Hangman/hs_err_pid11983.log"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to tell OSX to use the JDK (Java Development Kit) instead of the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

So, lets be certain you have installed the Sun **JDK** for osx.  here is a link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Then use spotlight (cmd-spacebar) to open "Java Preferences"
and only check the ones that say the same version info as that download (1.7) and uncheck the JRE ones.

Now your osx machine will be setup to use the JDK and android compiles/development should work a better when you restart your IDE.

Comment: I just did that. I am unsure where to uncheck JRE in Java Control Panel.

Comment: it will be in "Java Preferences",  just open spotlight, type in **Java Preferences** and click the entry named Java Preferences that appear. if the JRE onces do not appear that is ok. Its more important that the JDK ones are there and checked.

Comment: Why would this be a JDK vs JRE issue? this is a JVM crash. You only need the JDK if you need things like javac.

Comment: Because Android requires usage of the JDK, not JRE : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

Comment: Yeah but aside from the title of this question I can't see how this is Android specific. Is he/she running dalvik bytecode on a JVM? ain't gonna work...

Comment: I found out this is a JVM Issue. I am a HE to clarify. What would be a good example of dalvik bytecode.